# I can't use user input to change z-coordinates of a triangle using GLUT?

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry, user-input, glut

I'm trying to use GLUT and OpenGL to draw a triangle that will change its z-coordinates based off a user input. I can't get it working though; no compiler errors, but the triangle doesn't change when I press those keys. Does anyone know why?

```
/////////////////////////////
/////OPENGL ASSIGNMENT 1/////
/////////////////////////////

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> //Needed for "exit" function
#include <GL/glut.h>
using namespace std;




/////GLOBAL VARIABLES/////

float zCoord = -10.0;    

////Function Declarations/////

void initRendering();
void windowResize(int width, int height);
void keyBoardEvents(unsigned char key, int x, int y);   ///this is the function that         will use user input

void drawing();  /// Note: this is the function we will use to draw shapes using opengl   functions




////Function Definitions/////


 void initRendering()
{
     glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}


void windowResize(int width, int height) 
{
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(45.0, (double) width/ (double) height, 1.0, 200.0);       ////Note:     45.0 is the camera angle, w/h is the aspect ratio///          
}



void keyBoardEvents(unsigned char key, int x, int y) 
{    

switch (key)
{
case 27: exit(0);
    break;

case 'w': zCoord = zCoord + 5.0f;
    break;

case 's': zCoord = zCoord - 5.0f;
    break;

case 'r': zCoord = -5.0f;

    break;

}

if (zCoord < -30.0)       ////// here we ensure -5.0 > zCoord > -30.0
{
    zCoord = 30.0;
}

else if (zCoord > -5.0)
{
    zCoord = -5.0;
}

}




void drawing()     
{

//Standard OpenGL at the beginning of each drawing() function:
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
glLoadIdentity(); 

///Specifically to this one, drawing the rectangle:

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);    ////here we say start grouping the next 3 statements as 3 vertices of a triangle

glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, (float)zCoord);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.5f, (float)zCoord);
glVertex3f(-1.5f, 0.5f, (float)zCoord);

glEnd;

glutSwapBuffers();


}






int main(int argc, char** argv)      ////here we are passing some initial arguments to   main, that the user does not have to input
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE );     ///initiates things  like depth (DEPTH) and color (RGB)/////
glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);     /////the initial window size

glutCreateWindow("MentorAssignment_1");     /////here we using an OpenGL function to make a window of title MentorAssignment_1

initRendering();


//////HANDLER FUNCTIONS/////      ////These are functions that call other functions, like keyBoardEvents and drawing, every time glutMainLoop() runs

glutKeyboardFunc(keyBoardEvents);
glutDisplayFunc(drawing);
glutReshapeFunc(windowResize);

glutMainLoop(); ///The openGL function that ensures main runs infinitely! (until escape is pressed)

return 0;

}
```

Comment: **1.** You're missing the parentheses after `glEnd`; is that in your real code as well? **2.** `zCoord = 30.0` should be `zCoord = -30.0`, I assume. **3.** Can you confirm that the keys are handled correctly? I.e. if you move `exit(0);` to the reaction on `'w'`, will the app terminate when `w` is pressed?

Comment: I confirmed it; yes, when I move exit()0; to 'w' the program terminates when I press w.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing parentheses after `glEnd`, which means you're not calling the function, just taking its address. Issuing a buffer swap after a `glBegin()` can likely put OpenGL in error state and cause it to ignore all further rendering commands. The net effect would be the triangle seems not to move, simply because it's no longer redrawn.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I thought that at the end of every drawing() function you needed to put glutSwapBuffers()? When I remove this line, the window opened doesn't display anything at all. Do you know what I should do to the glutSwapBuffers() line?

Comment: @user3430312 Yes, swap should be there. But does anything change if you actually call `glEnd()`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to call glutPostRedisplay() at the end of your keyBoardEvents function to indicate to GLUT that the frame should be redrawn.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed my problem completely :)